# on scroll Cannot read property 'top' of undefined in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I apologize if this question has already been answered. I've tried searching for solutions but could not find any that suited my code. I'm still new to jQuery.

```
var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
$('#navbar li').each(function () {
    var currLink = $(this);
    var manurl = $(currLink).find('a').attr("href");
var url = '';
    if(manurl != "#"){ 
    console.log(manurl);

    var type = manurl.split('#');
    var refElement = '';
    if(type.length > 1)  refElement = type[1];
    console.log(refElement + "sssss");
    if(refElement != ''){
        refElement = $(refElement);
        if (refElement.position().top - 500 <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
            console.log(refElement);
        } else {
              console.log(refElement+"ssssss");
        }
    }
    }else{
        console.log("qq");
    }
});
```

Comment: Do not remove the hash (#) character like manurl.split('#'). $(refElement) has be something like $("#someid")

Comment: thank u for giving answer but i want only # value from url

Comment: yes but that does not correspond to an element!

Comment: so can i add manully add # before?

Comment: you can but you seem to already have it in the href like <a href="#someid"....>. I guess the intention is to scroll to an element with someid, in that case just get the href as it is and don't split.

Comment: yeah but some url i don't have # and some url i have like <a href="www.xyz.com#xyz" >

Comment: Ok then, split the hash part and add manually. You can use a regex too but let's try this first. Something like `"www.xyz.com#xyz".match(/\b#\w+$/)[0]` will give you what you want as well

Comment: hello if i have link like "www.xyz.com#xyz" and i don't have id xyz on there page for that this error come .. what condition i aaply if don't have id on that page and ignor it.

Comment: First, when you split, filter your array so it doesnt have empty string like this: `var type = "www.xyz.com#".split("#").filter(function(d){return d})` . Then, in your if statement just do `if(refElement && (refElement = $(refElement))){..` so I moved the first line after your if inside your if and it will only be done if refElement is a truthy value. Try this and let me know